# RTL-SDR in GNU Radio 3.9

Tags: python, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr

I'm trying to make the RTL-SDR receive WBFM through GNU Radio (with Ubuntu 20.04), with this flowgraph:

[GNU Radio flowgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unsfR.png)

But when I execute, it gives me this error message:

```
gr-osmosdr 0.2.0.0 (0.2.0) gnuradio 3.8.1.0
built-in source types: file osmosdr fcd rtl rtl_tcp uhd miri hackrf bladerf rfspace airspy airspyhf soapy redpitaya freesrp 
Using device #0 Realtek RTL2838UHIDIR SN: 00000001
Found Rafael Micro R820T tuner
[R82XX] PLL not locked!
Exact sample rate is: 2000000,052982 Hz
[R82XX] PLL not locked!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtl_sdr_receive.py", line 270, in <module>
    main()
  File "rtl_sdr_receive.py", line 246, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "rtl_sdr_receive.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.connect((self.rtlsdr_source_0, 0), (self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/hier_block2.py", line 37, in wrapped
    func(self, src, src_port, dst, dst_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/hier_block2.py", line 100, in connect
    self.primitive_connect(*args)
TypeError: primitive_connect(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: gnuradio.gr.gr_python.hier_block2_pb, block: gnuradio.gr.gr_python.basic_block) -> None
    2. (self: gnuradio.gr.gr_python.hier_block2_pb, src: gnuradio.gr.gr_python.basic_block, src_port: int, dst: gnuradio.gr.gr_python.basic_block, dst_port: int) -> None

Invoked with: <gnuradio.gr.gr_python.top_block_pb object at 0x7fae1b571af0>, <Swig Object of type 'gr::basic_block_sptr *' at 0x7fae1740c9c0>, 0, <gnuradio.gr.gr_python.hier_block2_pb object at 0x7fae19809770>, 0
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'gr::basic_block_sptr *', no destructor found.
```

I'm using the GNU Radio 3.9 version because is the only one that works with rpitx (with TCP connection). But it seems to have trouble dealing with the RTL-SDR. Is this a software bug or I misconfigured something? Already tried to install GNU Radio 3.9 from PPA and from source, with same results in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using the **GNU Radio 3.9**

> gr-osmosdr 0.2.0.0 (0.2.0) **gnuradio 3.8.1.0**

The most probable reason is that gr-osmosdr OOT module was build for gnuradio **3.8.1.0** but you are using gnuradio **3.9**. You can't mix versions like this. You need to install gr-osmosdr version that was built for your gnuradio version (or rebuild/reinstall from source).